# When to use 'great interest' vs 'a great interest'

Tags: grammar

"I have read your letter with great interest" sounds more correct to me than if I were to write, "I have read your letter with a great interest".

However a sentence like, "she expressed a great interest in your letter" sounds more correct than if I wrote it without the "a".

Is this just personal taste (both ways being correct) or is there an actual rule which determines when/where you should use "a great interest" vs without the "a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to when "an interest" is used, against "great interest".

"An interest" or "a --- interest" is mostly used when the subject of interest is being mentioned, like in "She had a huge interest in calligraphy".

Whereas "great interest" is used when the subject has been mentioned previously or is understood, as in "I have read your letter with great interest", or "..the articles being of particular interest to... ".